# Combining the use of Skip Tokens and Server-Side Filtering in WCF Data Services v2

Tags: wcf-data-services

How does one combine the use of filtering and server-side paging in WCF Data Services (version 2)?

In the code snippet below, the NextLinkUri is always has the $filter query param missing. I've tried contructing a new Uri with the NextLinkUri and adding the $filter param back in and executing this new Uri instead. Not surprisingly, this causes a server-sider error.

```
var query3 = ServiceContext.ConventionalReturnFacts;
var filterString = String.Format("CalendarDateId ge {0} and CalendarDateId lt {1}",
                    passedCalendarYear * 10000,
                    (passedCalendarYear + calendarYearIncrement) * 10000);
query3.AddQueryOption("$filter", filterString);

// Get first page of results
var response = query3.Execute();
result.Results = response.ToList();

// Get remaining pages (if any)
var continuation = ((QueryOperationResponse)response).GetContinuation();
while (continuation != null)
{
    // NextLinkUri is missing the $filter query parameter so pages 2 and
    // up end up having unfiltered entities!
   response = ServiceContext.Execute<ConventionalReturnFact>(continuation.NextLinkUri);        
   ((List<ConventionalReturnFact>)result.Results).AddRange(response.ToList());
   continuation = ((QueryOperationResponse)response).GetContinuation();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Client should not append any system query option to the URL of the next link. The next link is opaque to client.

In your case, the next link should return next page of filtered data. If not, it is a problem of service, not client.